# Vista de Diseñador en proyecto Crossplatform no funciona (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: visual-studio

Hace unos días instale visual 2017 Enterprise.

Cuando creo un proyecto C# Crossplatform, portable, encuentro que no puedo usar el diseñador para crear la UI de la aplicación.

Si puedo editar manualmente el archivo .xaml, pero es una locura.

El mensaje que me da visual estudio es "No hay editor disponible para C:...\ MainPage.xaml. Asegúrese que esta instalada la aplicación para esta clase de archivos (.xaml)"

Por otro lado, cuando creo un proyecto C# Android o C# iOS el diseñador funciona perfectamente.

Aclaro que estoy trabajando sobre una instalación limpia de Windows 10 Pro, totalmente actualizada, y con una licencia MSDN de Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, también totalmente actualizada.

Alguien que haya pasado por lo mismo, o que sepa como solucionarlo?

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo? a mi tampoco me funciona